# Unable to add Hover & focus effects to my react component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to create a reusable react component, so I have been passing props to make one. But I not able to apply the hover effects to the component.
I have tried to extend the styles in styled-component but it does not work.

Here's a link to the code Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-lake-2owfy?file=/src/components/InputComponent/InputSubComponent.js

Comment: here's the design:https://www.figma.com/file/slzHnI05qpbBeC33ZMZGa5/input-component?node-id=0%3A1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```css
export const Label = styled.label`
    &:hover {
        color:red;
    }
    font-family: Noto Sans JP;
    font-style: normal;
....
```